# PHP/MySQL Function result in a variable, e-mail checking

Tags: php, mysql, function, email

How can I use another function to check if the email is in the right format ([number of symbols]@[number of symbols].[number of symbols]) and if it's unique while adding it using the insertUser? (All info is read from a .txt file).

Code:

```
class User{

    function randomPassword($length = 8){
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }


    function insertUser($firstName, $lastName, $email){
    global $DB;
    $DB->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`fname`, `lname`, `password` , `email`) values ('$firstName', '$lastName', '" . randomPassword() . "', '$email') ");   

    }
```

In the index file:

```
$USER = new User(); 

     $data = readData();
     foreach($data as $nr => $user){
        $USER->insertUser($user['first_name'], $user['last_name'], $user['email']);
    }
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call as `$this->randomPassword();`

Email validation

```
function checkEmail($email) {
  if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])
  ?*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/",$email)){
    list($username,$domain)=split('@',$email);
    if(!checkdnsrr($domain,'MX')) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I put the function in the index file and it worked, by using $this-> I assume it will work from that file too? How about the email check?

Answer (score 1):

To insert the random string you should do this :

Change the insertUser function to :

```
function insertUser($firstName, $lastName, $email){
global $DB;
$DB->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`fname`, `lname`, `password` , `email`) values ('$firstName', '$lastName', '" . $this->randomPassword() . "', '$email') ");   

}
```